# stateless component call public method using ref

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a public method in SomeCompoent. How to call it at its parent?

```
const firstDateComponent = ({ month, year, navigate }) => {
  const firstDate = new Date(year, month, 1).getDay();

  function getEmptyDays(firstDate) {
    const emptyDays = [];
    for(let i=0; i < firstDate; i++) {
      emptyDays.push(
        <li className='month-day empty' key={ `${year}${month}-empty${i}`}>.</li>
      );  
    }
    return emptyDays;
  }

  if(navigate){
    //call the clear method here
  }


  return (
    <div>
      <ul className='months'>
          <SomeCompoent ref={param => this.__selection = param}>
            { getEmptyDays(firstDate) }
          </SomeCompoent>
      </ul>

      <p onClick={e => this.__selection.clear()}>this work if call in jxs</p>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I manage to call clear method in the jsx by using ref. But how can I call within the nagivate if statement?

Comment: you have keep if statement in function then only you can do it

Comment: @mellisa Could you close some of your previously asked questions? You've only accepted 5 answers from 33 issues that you've posted.

Comment: @JayantPatil like how?